# Can you store complex data types into RedisTimeseries instead of just a numeric value?

Tags: redis, redistimeseries

I would like to add different types to my Timeseries database. For example, I may want to store a byte string or hashmodel but it seems like it can't and instead I get `redis.exceptions.ResponseError: TSDB: invalid value`

Is there not a way to add other types other than values in RedisTimeseries?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Each sample must be composed of a 64-bit integer timestamp (milliseconds since the UNIX epoch) and a 64-bit floating-point value. That's it.

Comment: Is there a way to have much more complex data be stored in a timeseries fashion? I want to make use of the key timestamp, RANGE start end query and FILTER features of RedisTimeSeries and at the same time not be limited to just a numeric value. I would assume that this isn't the first time this problem has been encountered and its either that there is a pattern with RedisTimeseries that might address this, or it addresses a completely different use case and that there is a another pattern for what I am trying to do. I assume what I aim to do can be done with Redis however.

Comment: No. If you don't need aggregations maybe RedisJSON would be a better fit for your use case.

Comment: Does that still do queries with a given start/end timestamp and allow for filter by labels (or object attributes)? I am very much dealing with Timeseries data.

Comment: It seems like the way I will have to implement this is to use a sorted set with a timestamp as the score and the value a list of keys to a JSON or Hash object in the database. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hello, @LeanMan, can you please expand a little on your last comment? Thanks a lot